# Skip duplicates line, but there value to a dict in Pytho

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement, duplicates

Reading a CSV file. Now, For each row that I read from the file, I need to check if the name already exist in the list; if exist, then I need to skip that line, but add the date on the file to the date list (under class) of the object corresponding to that name. If doesn't exist, then this is the first time I'm seeing this person. and need to create new object in the dict,
This is how it looks so far:

```
class member:
    name = ""
    date = []

data = []

import csv
file = open("vaccination.csv")
columns = csv.reader(file)

next(columns)  
    
for column in columns:
    m = member()
    m.name = column[1] + " " + column[2]
    m.date = int(column[5])
    **if m.name in data():
        if m.name in data.key():    m.date.append(m)
    else:
        data.append({"name": m.name, "date": m.date})**
```

The CSV file:

```
Name   last name  Date in days
Terrance    Jaques  229
Yvonne  Fitzpatrick 258
Mario   Stricklin   146
Shaneka Wilson  227
Chiquita    Coffman 116
William Russell 181
George  Gagnon  197
Jean    Hibbler 101
Gary    Reeves  271
Terrance    Jaques  299
Sheila  Chestnut    277
Janice  Murphy  244
William Russell 107
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Generally when you read in your data from a file it is good practice to include a small subset of your data in your question so others can test it.

Comment: Also currently data is a `list` object, your question implies that you want to be adding your values from the csv into a `dict`. Perhaps also include a sample of what you want `data` to look like after you program runs.

Comment: Is that actually how your csv looks? That's not a validly formatted csv document, and when you read in you'll end up with elements that look like: `['Terrance    Jaques  229']` instead of `['Terrance', 'Jaques', '229']`

Comment: No, the file is too big, this is just few rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is an option if you want a `dict` keyed by name:

```py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def main():
    data = defaultdict(list)
    with open('vaccination.csv', 'r') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(csv_reader)  # Skip Header Row
        for row in csv_reader:
            name = f'{row[0]} {row[1]}'
            date = int(row[2])
            data[name].append(date)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

data:

```py
{'Terrance Jaques': [229, 299], 'Yvonne Fitzpatrick': [258],
 'Mario Stricklin': [146], 'Shaneka Wilson': [227],
 'Chiquita Coffman': [116], 'William Russell': [181, 107],
 'George Gagnon': [197], 'Jean Hibbler': [101],
 'Gary Reeves': [271], 'Sheila Chestnut': [277],
 'Janice Murphy': [244]}
```

---

You can turn `data` into a `list` of `dict` objects if that's they preferred way to have the information:

```py
lst = [{'name': k, 'date': v} for k, v in data.items()]
```

lst:

```py
[{'name': 'Terrance Jaques', 'date': [229, 299]},
 {'name': 'Yvonne Fitzpatrick', 'date': [258]},
 {'name': 'Mario Stricklin', 'date': [146]},
 {'name': 'Shaneka Wilson', 'date': [227]},
 {'name': 'Chiquita Coffman', 'date': [116]},
 {'name': 'William Russell', 'date': [181, 107]},
 {'name': 'George Gagnon', 'date': [197]},
 {'name': 'Jean Hibbler', 'date': [101]},
 {'name': 'Gary Reeves', 'date': [271]},
 {'name': 'Sheila Chestnut', 'date': [277]},
 {'name': 'Janice Murphy', 'date': [244]}]
```

---

Both of these were run on `vaccination.csv` which was reformatted as a valid csv:

```
"Name","last name","Date in days"
Terrance,Jaques,229
Yvonne,Fitzpatrick,258
Mario,Stricklin,146
Shaneka,Wilson,227
Chiquita,Coffman,116
William,Russell,181
George,Gagnon,197
Jean,Hibbler,101
Gary,Reeves,271
Terrance,Jaques,299
Sheila,Chestnut,277
Janice,Murphy,244
William,Russell,107
```